# Not able to validate email using regex in lex from lambda- python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am creating a chatbot for raising a ticket.I have a slot for validating emailid.I have my own regex in lambda .I want to validate xxx.yyy@gmail.com

When tested from lex,it accepts xxx@gmail.com but it does not accept xxx.yyy@gmail.com.It asks for the same prompt again.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
    val = ""
    slots = event['currentIntent']['slots']
    empidemployee= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["empidemployee"]
    latestdescription= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["latestdescription"]
    latestservice= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["latestservice"]
    latestimpact= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["latestimpact"]
    latesturgency= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["latesturgency"]
    email=event['currentIntent']["slots"]["email"]

    if not (re.search(regex,email)):
        output_session_attributes = event['sessionAttributes'] if event['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
        val =  elicit_slot(output_session_attributes,'latestdetails',slots,'email',"Oops! Your emailid is not correct Please enter again!" )
        
    
    else:
        

        send_email(empidemployee,email,latestdescription,latestservice,latestimpact,latesturgency)
        val = close()
    return val
```

Sample conversation:

```
Lex:Please provide me emailid
User:123
Lex:Oops! Your emailid is not correct Please enter again
User:www.yyy@gmail.com
Lex:Please provide me emailid
User:ccc@gmail.com
Lex:your ticket is raised
```

Comment: Your regex works, and since the second time you enter the email does not respond with "Oops!..." Then it is accepting the correct email input, but it might be going to the wrong slot, then eliciting email as the next slot. Or the close() function is not doing what you are expecting it to do.

You should log your event every time Lambda is run, and you can check the logs in CloudWatch. That will give you more insight into debugging.